# jQuery animate only when slider div active

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/duNHJ/2/

Basically there is an animations every div so when I click next or prev slider that animation script shoud run only when activated div. Currently it animates all of them at the beginning.

using http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

Also how can add active class on activated div?

Comment: jsFiddle is great for demonstration of the issue.  However, please include the actual code within the question to preserve the context for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't too sure what you wanted with regards to your first concern, however with regards to adding/remove an active state class, see the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/duNHJ/27/

Comment: works perfect so i can use like this so each div shows different animation:  after: function(el, next_el){
         $(next_el).addClass('active');   
    if ($('.page1').hasClass('active')) {}
   else {}
   if ($('.page2').hasClass('active')) {}
   else {}
    },
    before: function(el){
         $(el).removeClass('active');           
    }

Comment: Why not use HTML5 custom attributes and jQuery custom events, see the updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/duNHJ/43/

Comment: can u tell whats the difference which one is faster thx dude!

Comment: Logically the latter method would be faster as it's not having to evaluate whether the element references the active class. In addition it's more structured.

Answer (score 0):

Any script will simply be run as soon as it is loaded.  Also, with the selector `$('.test')`, the animation will be run on all elements with class `test`.  You want to animate when the div changes.  The jQuery Cycle Plugin provides callback methods to do this:

```
$('#example').cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollLeft', 
    timeout: 5000, 
    before:  onBefore, 
    after:   onAfter 
});
```

Where the function `onBefore()` is called before the transition, and `onAfter()` is called after.  In your case, just use `onAfter()` (and get rid of the inline scripts):

```
function onAfter() {
    // $(this) references the current slide
    $(this).animate({
        top: "100px"
    }, 1000);
}

$('#s6').before('<div id="nav">').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    timeout: 6000,
    delay: -2000,
    pager: '#nav',
    next: '#next2',
    prev: '#prev2',
    activePagerClass: 'activeSlide',
    after: onAfter
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/cmwc3/

I am not sure exactly what animation you want to happen, but this should get you started.

Comment: i wanted each div with different animations, but urs pretty close thx